# get dynamic item name in paypal buy now button

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

Please see this screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/feZvR.png

This is my form with a dropdown of 25 items in it.

The price for all the items are same so no worries about the price.

But the name of all the products are different.

I am facing difficulty in getting the Item Name dynamically in buy now button.

```
<input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value="">
```

Whenever user selects any option from dropdown, value="" must set with selected item's value and than go to paypal payment page (in php code or js code, anyone can do).

Can anyone suggest how to get this value dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you only want to have one "buy now" button:*

That should be doable with `jQuery`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('yourSelector').change(function() {
        $('#item_name').val($('yourSelector').text());
    });
});
```

replace 'yourSelector' with the id of your dropdown-menu. You could also do it with native javascript, though.

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="databasedb" name="databasedb" onChange="myFunction()">

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction()
      {
       $('yourSelector').change(function() {
       $('#item_name').val($('databasedb').text());
          });
      }
      </script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction()
      {
       $('databasedb').change(function() {
       $('#item_name').val($('databasedb').text());
          });
      }
      </script>

Comment: You should put this in a document.ready function, let me edit the code real quick. Also, are you using jQuery on your site and are there any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the name and the value in a array.
Then in a foreach() loop echo out all items like so:

```
<?php

$items = [
    'item1' => 'value1',
    'item2' => 'value2',
    'item3' => 'value3'
];

foreach ($items as $item => $value) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="' . $item . '" name="' . $item . '" value="' . $value . '">';
}

?>
```

Comment: I have only 1 dropdown to select only 1 item, not multiple.